# How to set language in moment js whole project-wide?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react project (npm, babel, es6). I would like to set language for WHOLE project. Not only for one file (what works). I checked a lot solution (ex. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1875#issuecomment-263220119) and it still doesn't work.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please share the relevant bits of code?

Comment: @Timo, I can share code, this settings for whole project settings and I would have to share whole project, what I can't do it. I just would like to use momentjs in my project, but need localization. When set lang in one module (file) it works, but I would like set once language in main app file (for example) and it will work everywhere.